# How would you define in typescript a recursive type for T: CustomObject | {[k:string] : T}?

Tags: typescript

Having a base type:

```
export type InnerType = { x: number; y: number };
```

I tried to define a type recursive to define a object that on every level it might be the base type or an object with any key -> recursion:

```
export type CustomType<T> =
 | {
  [label: string]: T;
 }
 | T;
```

and

```
export type CustomType<T> = {
 [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends T
 ? T
 : K extends string
 ? { [K: string]: T }
 : never;
};
```

But none of the above seems the correct way to model data structures like the following.

```
const a: CustomType<InnerType> = {
  x: 1,
  y: 12,
};

const b: CustomType<InnerType> = {
  level01: {
    x: 1,
    y: 12,
  } 
}

const c: CustomType<InnerType> = {
  level01: {
    x: 1,
    y: 12,
  },
  level2: {
    level21: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
    },
  }
 }

const d: CustomType<InnerType> = {
  level01: {
    x: 1,
    y: 12,
  },
  level2: {
    level21: {
      x: 1,
      y: 2,
    },
  },
  level3: {
    level32: {
      level321: {
        x: 1,
        y: 2,
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: I think the first one should do, but with `CustomType<T>` instead of just `T`: `type CustomType<T> = {
  [label: string]: CustomType<T>;
} | T;` I am not sure if this exactly what you want (although the examples pass).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the recursive part in `CustomType`, that's why currently it only accepts up to one level.

Define `CustomType` as:

```
export type CustomType<T> =
    | {
        [label: string]: CustomType<T>;
    }
    | T;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBXAzjCBbAFWWAB4CA+OAXgFgAoORuAHzgG96mu4BtAGwCGAI2B8AXHBxQAlgDsA5gF0JmHPiIoy5ANycmAXz2NWBXXXqhIsBMTgBJWbOBQNqKuzggJsjHhFRtOERvX384fTN6AGMIWRw4ARVsXEJiEgcnF2JKdw4GJi84AEYAGiMgiSKAJjK6CPpo2PihJLVUzQznVxz2cr5gADdRAAYiiTzuAsraycZg4prywzqGuhi4+CjWlNd0xy7s6l78xn6hvlHx8q5C0uumeeqZg2fTwdEqq5PuM4+x49mP3efCqRX+E0Bs0Ki2+kIelXuk2WgP0r3C9GWjQ2cAAJtt1GlOlkUD0IW9zpcAVDpoiKgs0ai+sDPlTJr8QeDaTcabDZvMYSiGWj2QBmL6A0UssmQyWc3lw25ouFzCQC5WM+XhIUY7RAA)

Comment: But this would allow having an empty object    const d: CustomType<InnerType> = {}; How about [K in keyof T].... conditional definition?